# Docker + Django + Vue.js + Webpack how to properly configure nginx?

Tags: django, docker, vue.js, nginx, webpack

At the moment I have the following configuration, in which I get an error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found)

As I understand it, I entered the path incorrectly and nginx cannot give the build.js file, which is missing from this path. How can I properly configure nginx so that it serves this file.

Config nginx:

```
upstream music {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name ***;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/logs.log;
    
    location /vue-frontend/ {
       root /app/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://music;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /staticfiles/ {
        root /home/app/web;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/app/web;
    }
}
```

The entire vue js project lies in the django project folder. Vue is embedded in the django template along the templates / base.html path

```
{% load static %}

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>     
        {% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <div class="main_content">
        <div id="app"></div>
        {% render_bundle 'main' %}
    </div>
    </body>
      
    </html>
```

file docker-compose.prod.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: gunicorn music.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/static
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/media
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file: 
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on: 
      - db
  vue:
    build:
      context: ./vue-frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    volumes: 
      - vue_dist:/app/dist
    depends_on: 
      - web
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0
    volumes: 
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file: 
      - ./.env.prod.db
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/static
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/media
      - vue_dist:/app/dist
    depends_on:
      - web
      - vue
volumes: 
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
  vue_dist:
```

In my index.html(base.html) layout

```
...
    <body>
      <div class="main_content">
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://*.*.*.*/vue-frontend/dist/build.js" ></script>
    </div>
    </body>
...
```

Comment: What happens if you place the following within the `location /vue-frontend/` block, on line 2 after the `alias`?   `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;`

Comment: Nothing, everything is the same, nginx tries to find the index.html file, which also does not exist, nginx says that the build.js file does not exist, but when I go to this path in the docker container, through which nginx is trying to get it, it does exist.

Comment: Do the other nginx routes work?

Comment: Yes staticfiles,media and django /

Comment: Need some more info:  1) Do you actually have an index.html file in vue-frontend or only in its dist subdirectory?  2) Do you want traffic to vue-frontend to go straight to dist or no?  3) What URL are you typing to access the index page?

Comment: 1)I don't have the index.html file in vue at all, since this file is given by django, where I embed the vue component using the compiled file vue-frontend / dist / build.js.
2)As I understand it, nginx should take the built build.js file (in the dist folder) and embed it in the index.html that django gave, but nginx does not see this file.
3)Any Django will always return index.html. If this url is specified in django urls.

Comment: When I visit any page other than the /admin page, nginx show me
nginx_1  | 2020/11/07 18:46:49 [error] 19#19: *2 open() "/home/app/web/vue-frontend/dist/build.js" failed (2: No such file
 or directory), client: *.*.*.*, server: *.*.*.*, request: "GET /vue-frontend/dist/build.js HTTP/1.1", host: "*.*.*.*", referrer: "http://*.*.*.*/en/landing/"

Comment: Having entered the container along this path, I find that the file is in place, but it is not served.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (untested, I don't have access to an nginx server at the moment):

```
location /vue-frontend/ {
   alias /home/app/web/vue-frontend/;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /vue-frontend/dist/build.js;
}
```

The idea is to serve `build.js` for any 404 to `vue-frontend`

Comment: nginx_1  | 2020/11/07 20:21:39 [error] 19#19: *27 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/
vue-frontend/dist/build.js", client: *, server: *, request: "GET /vue-frontend/dist/build.js HTTP/1.1",
 host: "3.8.15.53", referrer: "http://*/en/landing/"

Comment: most likely it is looping and cannot find the file

Comment: I notice your docker file says: `/home/app/web/dist`.  No `vue-frontend`. Do you have the dist folder in two places?

Comment: thanks, in vue I replaced (- vue_dist: / home / app / web / dist) with (- vue_dist: / app / dist), in nginx (- media_volume: / home / app / web / dist) with (- vue_dist: / app / dist), in the nginx config I wrote location / vue-frontend / {root / app /; } and it all worked.